# How to store nested document as String in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, apache-kafka-connect

**Context:** 
1) We are building a CDC pipeline (using kafka & connect framework)

2) We are using debezium for capturing mysql Tx logs

3) We are using Elastic Search connector to add documents to ES index

**Sample change event generated by Debezium:**

```
{
    "source" : {
      "before" : {
        "Id" : 97,
        "name" : "Northland",
        "code" : "NTL",
        "country_id" : 6,
        "is_business_mapped" : 0
      },
      "after" : {
        "Id" : 97,
        "name" : "Northland",
        "code" : "NTL",
        "country_id" : 6,
        "is_business_mapped" : 1
      },
      "source" : {
        "version" : "0.7.5",
        "name" : "__",
        "server_id" : 252639387,
        "ts_sec" : 1547805940,
        "gtid" : null,
        "file" : "mysql-bin-changelog.000570",
        "pos" : 236,
        "row" : 0,
        "snapshot" : false,
        "thread" : 614,
        "db" : "bazaarify",
        "table" : "state"
      },
      "op" : "u",
      "ts_ms" : 1547805939683
    }
```

**What we want :**

**We want to visualize only 3 columns in kibana :**

1) before - containing the nested JSON as string

2) after - containing the nested JSON as string

3) source - containing the nested JSON as string

I can think below possibilities here :

a) Either converting nested JSON as string 
b) Combining column data in elastic search

I am a newbie to elastic search . Can someone please guide me how to do that.

I tried defining custom mapping as well but it is giving me exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can always view your document as a Raw JSON in Kibana.
You don't need to manipulate it before indexing in elastic.

As this is related to visualization, handle this in Kibana only.
Check this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/document-context.html) for a screenshot.

Refer [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/document-data.html#adding-columns) to add the columns which you want to see onto the results

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your use case, but if you would like to turn some json's to their representing strings, then you can use logstash for that, or even [Elasticsearch ingest capabilities to convert an object (json) to a string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/convert-processor.html).

From the link above, an example:

> PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline-id {   "description": "converts the
>   content of the id field to an integer",   "processors" : [
>       {
>         "convert" : {
>           "field" : "source",
>           "type": "string"
>         }
>       }   ] }